# How to deploy rasa chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have build a chatbot using rasa framework. Now I want deploy it over my website but I dont want deploy it using chatterbot or Docker. I am googling but I am not getting it.

How to deploy the chatbot on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install Rasa Core and Rasa using pip / anaconda as it is described  [here](https://rasa.com/docs/core/installation/) (Rasa Core) and [here](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/installation/) (Rasa NLU).
2. Train your Core and NLU model
3. Start NLU as server using `python -m rasa_nlu.server --path projects` (see [here](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/config/) for the docs). Do this using a tool like nohup so that the server is not killed when you close your terminal window
4. Edit the endpoint configuration file for Rasa Core so that it links to NLU (see docs [here](https://rasa.com/docs/core/server/#connecting-rasa-nlu)):

   `nlu:
        url: "http://<your nlu host>:5000"`
5. Decide how you want to connect the bot on your website to Rasa. It's probably either via [REST](https://rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/#rest-channels) or using [socketio](https://rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/#socketio-setup). Add configuration for the used channel to a credentials file, e.g. for REST

   `rest:
     # you don't need to provide anything here - this channel doesn't
     # require any credentials`
6. Run Rasa Core

   `python -m rasa_core.run -d <path to core model> \ 
       -u <nlu model you want to use> \
       --endpoints <path to your endpoint configuration (includes NLU url) \
       --credentials <channel credentials>`
7. Call the Rest or the socket io endpoint from your website. [Here](https://github.com/mrbot-ai/rasa-webchat) is a small chat widget which you can embed in your website and uses socketio to communicate with Rasa.

Comment: I have a static website  and I have converted into a flask app then run it. It is working fine. I dont want to use [this](https://github.com/mrbot-ai/rasa-webchat) widget. Can you please help how can I deploy on my static website

Comment: @Souren page can't display dynamic content without using JavaScript. If you don't want to use this widget then you will have to write something similar in JavaScript on your own. And it can be a lot of work. You can put widget on static page but it has to connect to server which can send dynamic data.